# Script - numberlines

Tags: scripting

I would like to make a script, which allows user to input some text and it will output the same text with number of lines.

Example:

Input:

```
Hi Jack,
how are you?
```

Output:

```
0001: Hi Jack,
0002: how are you?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution with `read`:

```
I=0; while read -r; do ((I++)); echo "$I: $REPLY"; done< test.txt;
```

where you can change test.txt to your script argument.

If you don't want to use bash variable `REPLY`:

```
I=0; while read -r LINE; do ((I++)); echo "$I: $LINE"; done< test.txt;
```

or something else instead of 'LINE'

Comment: Try `printf "%04d: %s\n" $I "$REPLY"` instead of the `echo...`, so that you get the desired format. Also consider what your `read` will do if given leading whitespace in the input, or a `\ ` character at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output through `nl`

Example

```
ls /etc | head | nl --number-separator=$':\t' --number-format=rz --number-width=4
0001:   alternatives
0002:   bash.bash_logout
0003:   bash.bashrc
0004:   bash_completion.d
0005:   csh.cshrc
0006:   csh.login
0007:   dbus-1
0008:   defaults
0009:   drirc
0010:   fonts
```

If you want the separation between the colon (`:`) and the input text to be just a single space, change the --number-separator argument from `$':\t'` to `': '`.

Comment: `nl -n rz -s ': ' -w 4` matches the example exactly.